# NullPointerException when passing a MediaPlayer object between classes

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, media-player

I'm trying to get the content for my MediaPlayer from another class but everytime I try it, it gives me a NullPointerException and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's the method that I've setup in the other class:

```
public MediaPlayer getName(int number) {

    switch (number) {

        case 1:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.john);

        break;

    }

    return mp;

}
```

So in my other class, I'm trying to retrieve it like this...

```
mp = myNameList.getName(number);
```

I am therefore setting my MediaPlayer instance in my original class to the retrieved data from the NameList class. As soon as I do anything, I get a NullPointerException on the getName method. Is there a better way of pulling such data and setting it in another class? I apologise if this question is a little bit all over the place but I'm really struggling to deal with this!

Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: What is the value of `number` when you call it the first time?

Comment: You should post more code, but most likely `myNameList` is null when you are calling `getName()`. Set a breakpoint and debug, see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

If `number != 1`, then mp will never be initialized as a new MediaPlayer object.  Also, are you sure that `myNameList` isn't null?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the responses. I don't think myName List is null, as I have this code above the method call - 'myNameList = new NameList();' and then after this I make the call as shown above 'mp = myNameList.getName(number);' but every time there is a NullPointerException on the getName method. Is there something I need to do in the class which has the getName method within it? Or does the problem lie with the class that is making a call to that method in the NameList class?